# Kernel is DOA for Linux-based Jupyter notebook (and Jupyter lab)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, kernel, julia, jupyter

So, after some trial-and-error, I managed to install Jupyter and its key GUIs (notebook and lab) using pip3. The jupyter notebook and the jupyterlab applications load fine. Whenever I try to create or access a notebook, however, the kernel is DOA. I tried restarting it without any luck. This is regardless of what language this kernel corresponds to (so it's not a language-specific problem). I encounter a similar question where the solution was ownership of the files in a certain folder, so I made sure that I maintain ownership of these files with my usual user (not root). Still, the problem persists. If you have any ideas as to how to resolve it, I'd be grateful. Cheers

Here is the error message I get, BTW:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 184, in start_kernel
    km, kernel_name, kernel_id = self.pre_start_kernel(kernel_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 172, in pre_start_kernel
    **constructor_kwargs
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 83, in create_kernel_manager
    km = kernel_manager_ctor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 73, in __init__
    super(Configurable, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1000, in __init__
    super_kwargs[key] = value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1131, in hold_trait_notifications
    self.notify_change(change)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1176, in notify_change
    c(change)
  File "/home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 819, in compatible_observer
    return func(self, change)
TypeError: _kernel_spec_manager_changed() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```